# How can I increase the spacing between this xy-picture and the text?

Tags: spacing, arrows, xy-pic

Often, when I have Xy-picture with a self-loop at the top, the arrow collides with the text above it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
\[\xymatrix{
    A\ar@(ul, ur)
}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Here are some of the things I tried already:

- This problem doesn't occur if the preceding line is the end of a paragraph. But in the context where this occurs, the diagram should be in the middle of a paragraph.
- Using `\vspace` works in this example, but sometimes adds space after the diagram instead. If possible, I'm interested in a solution for which I don't have to manually set spacing for each diagram.
- If I try to encase the diagram in an `\mbox`, it adds some space – but not enough.
- The amount of space depends greatly on latent variables: for example, if you use `A\ar@(ul, ur)^\phi` instead of `A\ar@(ul, ur)`, the diagram has the correct spacing. I'm interested in knowing why this happens.

Because this occurs multiple times in preexisting code, I would prefer an `Xy` solution rather than having to port everything to `tikz-cd`.

Comment: I'm not sure *why* this happens (which is why this is a comment), but enclose the `xymatrix` in an `fbox` to see what's really happening. Somehow the arrow being drawn is not taken into account when the 'bounding box' is calculated if a label is not specified. An uneducated guess at a fix would be to use `A\ar@(ul, ur)^{}` instead.

Comment: @Troy: that worked, see egreg's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curved arrows are drawn with a `\special` and they are outside the control of TeX as far as determining the bounding box is concerned, because they're typeset in a box with no width and height.

Adding a dummy label solves the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy} % otherwise arrow tips are ugly

\begin{document}

\noindent % just to make alike lines
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
\[\xymatrix{
    A\ar@(ul, ur)
}\]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
\[\xymatrix{
    A\ar@(ul, ur)^{}
}\]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
\[\xymatrix{
    A\ar@(ul, ur)_{}
}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks! So is the reason this works that the arrow is drawn with `\special` but any label, even an empty label, is typeset normally with a nonzero width and height?

Comment: @ArunDebray I don't know whether the empty label contributes height (I'd say no, as the result is the same with `^` and `_`); however its place contributes to the bounding box. Most likely the empty box containing the special is where the curved arrow starts; a small contribute comes from the arrow tip, but is insufficient.